How do I access the docs that have been retrieved by my retriever in ConversationalRetrievalChain?
I need access to the particular docs that have been retrieved by my retriever, so that i may know their page numbers.

function where i create and store the embeddings -

def create_embeddings_for_pdf(pdf_id: str, pdf_path: str):
    # text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    #     chunk_size=500,
    #     chunk_overlap=100
    # )

    loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_path)
    docs = loader.load_and_split()

    for doc in docs:
        doc.metadata = {
            "page": doc.metadata["page"],
            "text": doc.page_content,
            "pdf_id": pdf_id
        }

    vector_store.add_documents(docs)

note that i have commented out the text_splitter because I read another stackoverflow entry that suggested that i should make page-sized chunks instead of having it be a fixed number of characters (i.e. 500)

the function where i run the conversationalRetrievalChain to actually get answer to my input message.

from flask import Blueprint, g, request, Response, jsonify, stream_with_context
from app.web.hooks import login_required, load_model
from app.web.db.models import Pdf, Conversation
from app.chat import build_chat, ChatArgs

bp = Blueprint("conversation", __name__, url_prefix="/api/conversations")


@bp.route("/", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
@load_model(Pdf, lambda r: r.args.get("pdf_id"))
def list_conversations(pdf):
    return [c.as_dict() for c in pdf.conversations]


@bp.route("/", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
@load_model(Pdf, lambda r: r.args.get("pdf_id"))
def create_conversation(pdf):
    conversation = Conversation.create(user_id=g.user.id, pdf_id=pdf.id)

    return conversation.as_dict()


@bp.route("/<string:conversation_id>/messages", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
@load_model(Conversation)
def create_message(conversation):
    input = f"In addition to your answer to the user's query, return the page number of the valid document you have used to arrive at the answer, in the following format - Page: <page_number>, output: <answer_to_user_query> {request.json.get('input')}"
    streaming = request.args.get("stream", False)

    pdf = conversation.pdf

    chat_args = ChatArgs(
        conversation_id=conversation.id,
        pdf_id=pdf.id,
        streaming=streaming,
        metadata={
            "conversation_id": conversation.id,
            "user_id": g.user.id,
            "pdf_id": pdf.id,
        },
    )

    chat = build_chat(chat_args)   
    
    if not chat:
        return "Chat not yet implemented!"

    if streaming:
        return Response(
            stream_with_context(chat.stream(input)), mimetype="text/event-stream"
        )
    else:
        answer = chat.run(input)
        print(f"AI answer : {answer}")
        return jsonify({"role": "assistant", "content": answer})


don't bother about the streaming-related code, i have not implemented it yet. The else block will run each time.

definition of the chat chain

from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from app.chat.models import ChatArgs
from app.chat.vector_stores.pinecone import build_retriever
from app.chat.llms.chatopenai import build_llm
from app.chat.memories.sql_memory import build_memory

def build_chat(chat_args: ChatArgs):
    retriever = build_retriever(chat_args)
    llm = build_llm(chat_args)
    memory = build_memory(chat_args)

    chat_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        memory=memory,
        retriever=retriever,
        verbose = True
    )

    return chat_chain

my goal is to know the page number where the output has come from.
for this i believed that

using page-sized chunks for embedding, as well as ...
finding a way to access those selected docs by my retriever is necessary.

Do correct me if there is a better way of achieving said goal.

One way to look at this is to refer to the metadata key in the query result. The example should have a page key, which identifies the page number from the PDF.
